# How do I return the resonse from a PUT request when using async and await in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a function which is initiating a HTTP PUT request. This request returns a response which I'd like to return and access in another function as a comparison to a string.

This is the function :

```
public async updateRejectedToDraft(){
       const messageId = this.loadedMessageService.messageId;
       await this.http
                 .put(`${this.baseUrl}/updateReqStatusFromRejectedToDraft?messageId=${messageId}&makerId=${this.datastore.userId}`, {})
                 .toPromise()
                 .then( response => {
                     console.log(response);
                     if(response == "true") {
                       console.log("abc");
                     }
                 })        
  }
```

When I log the response, it returns "true" which is the expected value. However, when I try to compare it with a string "true", I don't get the same response. I want to return the response and compare it with a string in another function. How do I do that?

Comment: Does it return `"true"` or `true`?

Comment: It returns true

Comment: `true == "true"` => false, `"true" == "true"` => true. So if `response` is really `"true"` and not `true` it should log `"abc"`. So does `"abc"` get logged or not?

​

Comment: @user2978664 - you can just do `if (response) {` if it's really returning just `true` and not `"true"`

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the strict comparator (===). The strict comparison operator compares the value and the type of the operands. And then make up your mind if you want to compare against "true" or true. This should work.
So

```
if (response === "true")
```

or

```
if (response === true)
```